Computing Cellular Homology on Product of CW Spaces
Edit. To answer my question (a few months later), section 3.B of the appendix (Hatcher, pg. 268) provides a construction and description of homology groups on the induced CW structure of a product of CW spaces. The construction is done prior to "The Algebraic Künneth Theorem" and only requires knowledge up through chapter two. Specifically, Proposition 3B.1 provides a definition for the boundary operator, which allows us to then construct the homology groups over the space in a well-defined manner.

Original Question. I will run through a simple example, and I'm curious to see how correct everything here is.
Consider the topological space $S^1_{\alpha}\times S^1_{\beta}$. Equip each individual CW Complex with the structure $v_{\alpha}$ (0-cell), $e_{\alpha}$ (1-cell) and $v_{\beta}$ (0-cell), $e_{\beta}$ (1-cell) respectively. Hence, we can describe the CW structure on the product space as having {$\{v_\alpha\}\times\{v_\beta\}$} as the 0-cells, {$\{v_{\alpha}\}\times\{e_{\beta}\},$ $\{e_{\alpha}\}\times\{v_{\beta}\}$} as the 1-cells, {$\{e_{\alpha}\}\times \{e_{\beta}\}$} as the 2-cells. [Confusion Part!] Hatcher seemingly does not provide a definition for the boundary operator on the chain groups. My current guess is that it can be defined $d^{n}=d_{\alpha}^{n-k}\times d_{\beta}^{k}$ for any $k\in$ {$0,...,n$}, which does work for this example, though generally does not seem suitable nor well-defined.
While I do believe that this example will give the correct results up to isomorphism, there are other examples where this doesn't seem well defined (e.g. $T^2\ \bigsqcup\ [0,1]$). These sorts of homology groups were never discussed in Hatcher, so it's never been something I've ever been too sure I've done correctly...I appreciate any and all help I can get. Thanks all!

When you say “for any $k$,” don’t you mean to write a sum over all such $k$? … Please elaborate carefully on your last paragraph; I cannot figure out what your issue is.

@TedShifrin I think this is my problem actually: I don’t have a well-defined boundary operator. If it were the sum, I don’t believe the map would be well-defined. For instance, $d_0\times d_1$ would not be defined on an $n$-cell such as {$e_{\alpha}$}$\times${$v_{\beta}$}). (p.s. I’m a UGA undergrad who has read through your Math3500/3510/4000/4010 textbooks. It is a pleasure to see you hear. :) )

I read too quickly. My sum comment still applies (with the interpretation that a boundary map is $0$ if it's applied to a cell of the wrong dimension), but you need a "product rule" for your boundary. You should have $d=\sum d_\alpha^{n-k}\times\text{id}\beta^k \pm \text{id}\alpha^{n-k}\times d_\beta^k$. Try this out just for $D^1\times D^1$ and $D^2\times D^1$. (Enjoy your math time at UGA. I miss my days teaching there.)

I don't know what you mean by "never discussed in Hatcher". Hatcher certainly discusses the cellular complex for a product. Could you elaborate on the $T^2\sqcup[0,1]$ "issue"?

@FShrike Hello. Do you know specifically where in Hatcher this topic is discussed? I've run through until the end of chapter two again, and I've found myself with the same issue. Specifically, I'm looking for a well-defined boundary operator on the CW complex structure on the product topology induced by the individual CW spaces involved in the product. (i.e. If $X,Y$ are CW, then $X\times Y$ inherits CW structure as detailed in original post.) Ted gave a good definition, though I'm curious to see an answer from Hatcher (or if you can testify on behalf of Ted's definition). Thank you.

@JAG131 I think it’s discussed in either the appendices to chapter two or in chapter three. It comes with a discussion of Tor groups for more complex products; it’s part of a package of Künneth-type theorems

@FShrike Just found it. Section 3.B of the appendix discusses everything. Thank you again!
